# mysql select products which appear in as many lines as quantities have in orders

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Having a table like this

```
+--------+------------+------------+
| orderID | productID | quantity   |
+--------+------------+------------+
|    100 |         10 |         1  |
|    100 |         11 |         1  |
|    101 |         10 |         1  |
|    101 |         11 |         2  |
|    101 |         12 |         1  |
+--------+------------+------------+
```

Is it possible to have a query and obtain records like following?

```
+--------+------------+
| orderID | productID |
+--------+------------+
|    100 |         10 |
|    100 |         11 |
|    101 |         10 |
|    101 |         11 |
|    101 |         11 |
|    101 |         12 |
+--------+------------+
```

That is, that a product appears in as many lines as quantities it has in a order.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive subquery:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select orderid, productid, 1 as n, quantity
      from t
      union all
      select orderid, productid, n + 1, quantity
      from cte
      where n < quantity
     )
select orderid, productid
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=edb14e84e9fe7c12283925d3d79eedb6) is a db<>fiddle.